# Echo two array at a time

Tags: php

I wanted to `echo` two array at a time. Please check bellow there i am already having echo of `$another_arr1` array and now i want to echo another `$another_arr2` array. How can i do it?

```
$arr1 = array('a'=>'1');
$arr2 = array('a'=>'2');
$arr3 = array('a'=>'3');
$another_arr1 = array($arr1,$arr2,$arr3);
$arr4 = array('b'=>'4');
$arr5 = array('b'=>'5');
$arr6 = array('b'=>'6');
$another_arr2 = array($arr4,$arr5,$arr6);

foreach ($another_arr1 as $_another_arr1){
    foreach ($_another_arr1 as $another1){
        echo $another1.' ->'.' need to put $another_arr2 value here <br/>';
    }

}
```

Comment: `foreach ($another_arr1 as $key=> $_another_arr1){
    foreach ($_another_arr1 as $another1){
  $another_arr2_value = (!empty($another_arr2[$key]['b']))? $another_arr2[$key]['b']:'';
        echo $another1.' ->'.' $another_arr2_value.'<br/>';
    }

}`

Comment: one correction in my comment . remove `'` from `.' $another_arr2_value.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
foreach ($another_arr1 as $key=> $_another_arr1){ 
  foreach ($_another_arr1 as $another1){ 
      $another_arr2_value = (!empty($another_arr2[$key]['b']))? $another_arr2[$key]['b']:''; 
      echo $another1.' ->'. $another_arr2_value.'<br/>'; 
  } 
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/728096

Comment: Smith Kr glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index of first array to get to the second array the use index b to check the data.Try this:

```
$arr1 = array('a'=>'1');
$arr2 = array('a'=>'2');
$arr3 = array('a'=>'3');
$another_arr1 = array($arr1,$arr2,$arr3);
$arr4 = array('b'=>'4');
$arr5 = array('b'=>'5');
$arr6 = array('b'=>'6');
$another_arr2 = array($arr4,$arr5,$arr6);

foreach ($another_arr1 as $key=>$_another_arr1){
    foreach ($_another_arr1 as $another1){
    $another_arr2_value = (!empty($another_arr2[$key]['b']))? $another_arr2[$key]['b']:'';//check if value in second array exists 
    echo $another1.' ->'. $another_arr2_value."<br>";
    }

}
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/88fca0d3989457b4333d23e579f9ae13b2f7711c)

Comment: you have copy-pasted one line code from my comment.BTW no issue

Comment: @Anant No i took your idea and corrected the code ,initially code in  your comment was wrong i fixed it before you.Ha Ha ha...

Answer (score 0):

use the below code:

```
<?php
$arr1 = array('a'=>'1');
$arr2 = array('a'=>'2');
$arr3 = array('a'=>'3');
$another_arr1 = array($arr1,$arr2,$arr3);
$arr4 = array('b'=>'4');
$arr5 = array('b'=>'5');
$arr6 = array('b'=>'6');
$another_arr2 = array($arr4,$arr5,$arr6);

foreach ($another_arr1 as $key=>$value){
    foreach ($value as $key1=>$value1){
        echo $value1.' -> '.$another_arr2[$key]['b'].'<br/>';
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it ion this way.

```
$arr1 = array('a' => '1');
$arr2 = array('a' => '2');
$arr3 = array('a' => '3');
$another_arr1 = array($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
$arr4 = array('b' => '4');
$arr5 = array('b' => '5');
$arr6 = array('b' => '6');
$another_arr2 = array($arr4, $arr5, $arr6);

foreach ($another_arr1 as $kk => $_another_arr1) {
  foreach ($_another_arr1 as $another1) {
    echo $another1 . $another_arr2[$kk]['b'] . '<br/>';
  }
}
```